# Why does Vim Automatically Change Comma Delimited CSV to Pipes?

Tags: vim, csv, vi, macvim

I open a comma separated CSV file with text wrangler and textedit and it shows comma `,` separated values.

However, opening with MacVim gives me a pipe `|` delimited file.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: You have installed a CSV plugin that does that for you. And before replying "no, I haven't", check the docs of your Vim distro. – Solution: Remove the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be a plugin that I installed.  Not sure which one.  I just did a clean install of Vim because my original was jammed with plugins I downloaded to test.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.

There's a popular plugin called [`csv.vim`](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim#concealing) that has the behaviour you describe. This plugin is used by the language-pack plugin, [`vim-polyglot`](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot).

As you can see in the `csv.vim` docs, you can stop it from replacing `,` with `|` if you put this in your `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:csv_no_conceal = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet to your .vimrc file

let g:csv_delim = ','

It overrides any plugins changing the delimiter on a csv file.